# what causes mapreduce job to create only one map for 100000 rows in hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I would like to know what configuration causes mapreduce to have only one map while input split of 10000 and lines per map of 1000 are set in job configuration.

Its a 2 node cluster and i tried scan with startRow and endRow.

I want to have atleast 2 maps, one on each machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a row key issue. Row key is composed of same prefix and are stored in only one RS.

Answer (score 1):

M/R tasks on HBase tables are split, by default, on region boundaries.  If you only have one region for 10K rows, you will only get one mapper.

If you only have one region, then you can simply split the regions in your table and have 2 regions, and thus 2 mappers.

Comment: i have 50+ regions on each node. and i get 10k rows everyday.. is it feasible to split region every day ? is there any alternative than splitting regions manually

Comment: It would have been helpful to mention that up front.  As @tousif said, it is a row key issue.  What you want is to have your keys randomly distributed across your regions, either by using some hash of your real key, or by using a salt prefix